# How to change font size, padding of chart title only, in chart.js 3.x

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to reduce padding and increase title text font size , I went though few example but dont seem to work. Even on placing the parameter at multiple places.

```
const labels1_1 = ['1','2','3', '4', '5','6','7', '8','9+'];
const data1_1 = {
  labels: labels1_1,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Trucks',
    data: [1,2,3, 4, 5,6,7, 8,9],
    backgroundColor: '#4472C4',
    borderColor: '#4472C4',
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};  
const config1_1 = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1_1,
    options: {
      title:{
        padding:5,
        fontSize:18
      },

        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Number of SS vs Number of Trucks',
                padding:5,
                fontSize:18

            },
            datalabels: {
              align: 'end',
              anchor: 'end',
              backgroundColor: '#3472C4' 
              },
            

            
        },
    
      scales: {
               
        y: {
            display:true,
          beginAtZero: true,
          title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'SS'
          }
          
        },
                
      }
    },
  };

const myChart1_1 = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart1_1'), config1_1);
```

I went through https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/configuration/title.html but didnt help. Also how to mention it globally so all titles have bigger font. text: 'Number of SS vs Number of Trucks' is the title.

Answer (score 7):

The Title options have evolved quite a bit in v2 of Chartjs. I found that the title was hidden entirely until I added padding - for one example

```
options: {
      plugins: { 
        title: {
          display: true, 
          text: "Title" ,
          padding: {
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10
          },
          font: {
            size: 24,
            style: 'italic',
            family: 'Helvetica Neue'
          }
        }
      },
      ... other options here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't help is because you are looking at the docs for version `2.8.0` as you can see in the url, the latest version is `3.6.2` and has some breaking changes against v2.

To adjust the font propertys you will need to define them in the font object in the title config like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Number of SS vs Number of Trucks',
        font: {
          size: 30
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

latest V3 documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/